# Every time I use .update(release_time=initial_time) i get an error 'int' object is not iterable but if I change it into .all() it works just fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Here is my code :

```
def release_it(request, id):
if request.method == "POST":
    x = Lap.objects.get(pk=id)
    x.released = True
    p = request.POST["release_time"]

    initial_time = datetime.strptime(p, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')

    x.release_time = initial_time
    x.save()

    load = Loaded.objects.filter(lap=id).update(release_time=initial_time)

    for l in load:

        l.save()
    return render(request, "race/index.html", {
        "message":"released!",
        "x":x,
        "load":load
        })
return render(request, "race/index.html", {
    "message":"released!"
    })
```

I get this error:

File "/Volumes/John HDD/Visual Studio Code /CS50-web-Programming-with-Python-and-JavaScript/Project/pigeon_race/race/views.py", line 27, in release_it
for l in load:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

but when i replace `load = Loaded.objects.filter(lap=id).all()`. it work just fine

Here is my model:

```
class Loaded(models.Model):
race_id = models.CharField(max_length=64)
lap = models.CharField(max_length=64)
lap_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

pigeon_id = models.CharField(max_length=65)
pigeon_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
pigeon_ring = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
pigeon_hcode = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=64)

release_time = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=64)
clock_time = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=64)
```

Comment: You need to add a tag for the framework you're using.

Comment: good day , i am using django, can you solve it , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update returns *a number of records* updated by a query. (not exactly updated, but matched a filter clause - [more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update))
You may just query records once again after update..

```py
Loaded.objects.filter(lap=id).update(release_time=initial_time)
load = Loaded.objects.filter(lap=id).all()
```

Comment: wow it worked!! very simple i spent hours pulling my hair for this thank you really, i have consumed my braincells for the day ,

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: spasibo ^_^ to you